# Geting key value of the dropdown list in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get the 'key' value of my dynamic dropdown list as follows:

```
searchSubmit(e){    
  const s = e.target.value;
  alert(s);
}
```

my dropdown list is as follows:

```
<select
  className="textboxstyle"
  onChange={this.searchSubmit}
>
  <option key='-1'>Select Brand</option>
  <option key='0'>ALL</option>
  {optionItems}
</select>
```

And my dynamic drop-down is populated as follows,

```
let brands = this.state.brands;
let optionItems = brands.map((brand) =>
  <option key={brand.id}>{brand.name}</option>
);
```

But when I select option, alert display the name of the selected value, not the key. How to get the 'key' value?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `key` prop is used by React to differentiate between all the elements in an array. If you want `value` to be the `id` of the `brand`, you can use it as `value` as well as `key`.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    brands: [{ id: 1, name: "Foo" }, { id: 2, name: "Bar" }]
  };

  searchSubmit = e => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    alert(value);
  };

  render() {
    const { brands } = this.state;

    return (
      <select onChange={this.searchSubmit}>
        <option value="-1">Select Brand</option>
        <option value="0">ALL</option>
        {brands.map(brand => (
          <option value={brand.id} key={brand.id}>
            {brand.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: and how do I get the 2 values ​​`brand.key` and `brand.name`?